# how to create a generic constructor for a generic class in java?

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a KeyValue class but in generic manner and this is what I've written:

```
public class KeyValue<T,E> 
{

    private T key;
    private E value;
    /**
     * @return the key
     */
    public T getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    /**
     * @param key the key to set
     */
    public void setKey(T key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public E getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    /**
     * @param value the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(E value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public KeyValue <T, E>(T k , E v) // I get compile error here
    {
        setKey(k);
        setValue(v);
    }
}
```

the error says : "Syntax error on token ">", Identifier expected after this token"

how should I create a generic constructor in java then?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight has the right answer.  Just wanted to mention that AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K,V> does what you want.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You need to remove `<T, E>` from the constructor's signature: it's already there implicitly.

```
public KeyValue(T k , E v) // No compile errors here :)
{
    setKey(k);
    setValue(v);
}
```

Comment: you can use bounds wherever possible, for example

    public class KeyValue<T extend Number,E extends SomeClass> 

so that it is more type safe

Comment: @PragalathanM That's certainly true, but it goes way beyond the help with a trivial syntax error in the OP.

Comment: Just want to point out, so the OP knows: The constructor here is *NOT* generic. The class is. Generic methods (and constructors) and generic classes are completely different things.

Answer (score 3):

Write constructor exactly the same way you wrote other methods

```
public KeyValue(T k , E v) 
    {
        setKey(k);
        setValue(v);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the constructor can be written as

```
public<T,E> KeyValue(T k,E v){}
```

but its not necessary also we can write`public KeyValue(T k,E v)`