# Java interfaces: compiler error

Tags: java, compiler-construction, interface, constructor

I was playing around with java interfaces a little and tried to implement a stack.
However, as soon as I added the constructor I got a compiler error:

```
./DefaultStack.java:5: error: <identifier> expected
DefaultStack<T> () {
                  ^
```

Here's my code:

```
public class DefaultStack<T> implements Stack<T> {
    DefaultStack<T> () {

    }
}
```

This is probably a really obvious mistake, but I'm kinda new to Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `<T>` from the constructor's signature.Write constructor exactly the same way you wrote other methods

```
DefaultStack()
{

}
```

More Info :[how to create a generic constructor for a generic class in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680442/how-to-create-a-generic-constructor-for-a-generic-class-in-java)

Comment: I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes, feels like you can't do that within the first 15 mins of asking.