# How use a generic type in constructor of class (Java)

Tags: java, generics, constructor

I'm looking for a way to allow the constructor of this class take in an array of a generic type.

```
public class my
{

   public my(T[] arr)  // how resolve this
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: This can be found in the Java documentation on Generics. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: `public class my<T>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a generic constructor for a generic class in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680442/how-to-create-a-generic-constructor-for-a-generic-class-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways for you to have a type array as a parameter in your constructor. One, you can add the parameter to the class like so...

```
public class my<T> {

   public my(T[] arr)
   {
        ...
   }

}
```

Or, your constructor can take in a Type Parameter, like so:

```
public class my {

   public <T> my(T[] arr)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

You can initialize an object of the first class like so:

```
my<SomeClass> varName = new my<>(arrayOfSomeClass);
```

And you can initialize an object of the second class like so:

```
my varName = new <SomeClass>my();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that in the second case, they might as well just do `public my(Object[] arr)`. Also, an explicit type witness is usually not needed when calling a generic method or constructor -- usually it is inferred; only when inference fails would you provide an explicit type witness.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any situation where I would want a generic constructor in a non-generic class. But hey, here you go:

You just add `<T>` to the constructor declaration:

```
public <T> my(T[] arr) {

}
```

Be careful when you call this constructor. Because it is generic, you can't use primitive types like `int` or `char`. You need to use their reference type counterparts, `Integer` and `Character`.

Answer (score 1):

add `<T>` along with the name of the class my

```
public class my<T> {
    public my(T[] arr) {
    }
}
```