# Java generic constructor

Tags: java, generics, constructor

```
Node( T itemArg, Node<T>  nextArg ) {

    this.item = itemArg;       
    this.next = nextArg;

}
```

Is this the right way to represent generic constructor

Comment: It would depends on what you are trying to do... but in principle, this is not incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a generic constructor for a generic class in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680442/how-to-create-a-generic-constructor-for-a-generic-class-in-java) You are correct that that would work.

Comment: General comment: This 'construct' resembles the old C-way of representing linked lists. In Java, we have many high-level data structures (including linked and double-linked lists), so this way of representing a linked list is not necessary.

Comment: The only slightly unusual thing here is unrelated to the generics: there is no need to call the parameter `fooArg` *and* qualify the field `this.foo`: `foo = fooArg;`, or renaming the parameter to `foo` and using `this.foo = foo;`, is more usual. But it isn't *wrong* to do it like this.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, as long as the parameter is specified in the class definition.

EDIT: Ensure item is an instance of `T`, and next is an instance of `Node<T>`.

```
public class Node<T> {
  T item;
  Node<T> next;
  //your constructor
}
```

Comment: If you go there, you should also specifiy that `item` should be an instance of `T` and `next` an instance of `Node<T>`.